# TypeError for C dimension in matplotlib pcolormesh

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am grouping a dataframe via a certain column, and attempting to `pcolormesh` each grouped dataframe to its own subplot, ensuring that all subplots have the same bins.

My code is as follows:

```
abins, rbins = np.arange(0,25,1),np.arange(0,70,1)
A, R = np.meshgrid(np.deg2rad(15*abins),rbins)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4,subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"), figsize=(20,10),sharey=True)
k=0
for name, df in bigdf.groupby('sv'):
    pc = ax.reshape(-1)[k].pcolormesh(A,R,df.groupby([pd.cut(df.el, rbins), pd.cut(df.mlt, abins)])['vtec'].mean().unstack(), \
                                    cmap='RdBu_r')
    k+=1
```

However, when I run I get the following error:

`TypeError: Dimensions of C (58, 16) are incompatible with X (25) and/or Y (70); see help(pcolormesh)`

I believe that there is something going on with A and R, since when I run

```
abins, rbins = np.arange(0,25,1),np.arange(0,70,1)
A, R = np.meshgrid(np.deg2rad(15*abins),rbins)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4,subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"), figsize=(20,10),sharey=True)
k=0
for name, df in bigdf.groupby('sv'):
    pc = ax.reshape(-1)[k].pcolormesh(df.groupby([pd.cut(df.el, rbins), pd.cut(df.mlt, abins)])['vtec'].mean().unstack(), \
                                    cmap='RdBu_r')
    k+=1
```

without A and R, I get the following result:

[image]

but I require `A` and `R` so that I have my desired bins. Alternatively something could be going on in the `pd.cut`, but I do not know much about this function.

Any ideas? I can provide the dataframe if necessary, but for reproducability, column el, and mlt can be random values within `rbins` and `abins`, respectively. And `vtec` can just be a random set of values.

EDIT: Here is a subsection of the dataframe to reproduce the problem https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qEn6i2zU6sblY9kwfMPrDRY8rXS9i0Gj

I believe the error is occurring due to `pd.cut()` discarding desired bins when no values fall in them. Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: It definitely does make sense to provide a minimal running code ([mcve]). That would include a toy dataframe created from random numbers or structured number space, indeed. The important bit is that whoever runs your code sees exactly the same error you report about.

Comment: I have now included example data to reproduce the problem. Along with a theory as to why the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` and `reindex` to force the `pd.groupby` after `pd.cut` to keep empty bins, even if there are no data to populate them:

```
abins, rbins = np.arange(0,25,1),np.arange(0,70,1)
A, R = np.meshgrid(np.deg2rad(15*abins),rbins)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,4,subplot_kw=dict(projection="polar"), figsize=(20,10),sharey=True)
k=0
for name, df in bigdf.groupby('sv'):
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([rbins, abins])
    pc = ax.reshape(-1)[k].pcolormesh(A,R,df.groupby([pd.cut(df.el, rbins), pd.cut(df.mlt, abins)])['vtec'].mean().reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan).unstack(), \
                                    cmap='RdBu_r')
    k+=1
```

Which gives the desired output:

[image]